# Question about vector space representation of field extension $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta)}$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I know that the field extension $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta)}$, where $\zeta = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-3}$ can be represented as a six dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with basis $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}, \zeta, \sqrt[3]{2}\cdot \zeta, \sqrt[3]{4} \cdot \zeta \}$. I am experimenting with a matrix representation of this vector space.

Is $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}, \sqrt{-3}, \sqrt[3]{2}\cdot \sqrt{-3}, \sqrt[3]{4} \cdot \sqrt{-3} \}$ also a basis of the vector space representing $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta)}$?

If not, then why not?

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: Good, I thought so. Just wanted to be absolutely sure.

Comment: You can use the replacement theorem to remove the vectors and add the new ones suitably.